# PyQt5 - Updating DataFrame behind QTableWidget

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am having problems with the Qt method to update a DataFrame if it has a specific element modified by the user in the GUI.

For example, when I run the following code, I get a 10 by 3 DataFrame with random values displayed. If I try to change any cell to value 400, I double click, type 400 and then press enter. When I print the DataFrame, the value is still the old value. I would like the DataFrame cell to update on user changing the value.

Many thanks!

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt, QTimer

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(700, 100, 350, 380)
        self.createTable()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.button = QPushButton('Print DataFrame', self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.print_my_df)
        self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click_table)
        self.show()

    def createTable(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.df_rows = 10
        self.df_cols = 3
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(self.df_rows, self.df_cols))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.df_rows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(self.df_cols)
        for i in range(self.df_rows):
            for j in range(self.df_cols):
                x = '{:.3f}'.format(self.df.iloc[i, j])
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(x))

    @pyqtSlot()
    def print_my_df(self):
        print(self.df)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click_table(self):
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print((currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column()))
            self.print_my_df()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`QTableWidget` does not know about the existence of the `DataFrame` so it is not updating it. We must update it for this we use the `cellChanged` signal that gives us the row and column, then we use the `item()` method that returns the `QTableWidgetItem` given the column and row, then we use the `text()` method of `QTableWidgetItem`.

The data that is placed in the items in the user's edition can be of any type for example a text and this would generate an error since the `DataFrame` only accepts numerical values for this we must provide an input that validates for this we place a `QLineEdit` with a `QDoubleValidator`.

```
class FloatDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        editor.setValidator(QDoubleValidator())
        return editor


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, df, parent=None):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.df = df
        nRows = len(self.df.index)
        nColumns = len(self.df.columns)
        self.setRowCount(nRows)
        self.setColumnCount(nColumns)
        self.setItemDelegate(FloatDelegate())

        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                x = '{:.3f}'.format(self.df.iloc[i, j])
                self.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(x))

        self.cellChanged.connect(self.onCellChanged)

    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def onCellChanged(self, row, column):
        text = self.item(row, column).text()
        number = float(text)
        self.df.set_value(row, column, number)
```

Example:

```
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(700, 100, 350, 380)
        df_rows = 10
        df_cols = 3
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(df_rows, df_cols))
        self.tableWidget = TableWidget(df, self)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.button = QPushButton('Print DataFrame', self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.print_my_df)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def print_my_df(self):
        print(self.tableWidget.df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, `cellChanged` really blew the question wide open! :)

Comment: Wonderful, but when my dataframe index is not 0, 1, 2, 3..., it still puts 0, 1, 2, 3... as index, how to make it the actual data-frame index?